# Codeigniter 3 - медленная загрузка

Tags: php, codeigniter

Пользовался довольно долго Codeigniter 2 версии, нравилась быстрота работы.

Поставил недавно вышедшую 3 версию на опенсервер. Появилось чувство, что фреймворк стал работать дольше...

Начал копать в чем дело, оказалось что при подключении класса библиотеки базы данных, фреймворк при дефолтной странице грузится на целую секунду дольше...

```
Page rendered in 1.0395 seconds
```

Имхо это перебор, кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим? Или возможно это проблемы только на опенсервере, а на "нормальном" сервере будет норм? (сам еще не проверял)

мои настройки database.php:

```html
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'localhost',
 'username' => 'root',
 'password' => '',
 'database' => 'seocases',
 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => FALSE,
 'db_debug' => TRUE,
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: У меня на openserver все прекрасно работает - время загрузки страницы с 35 запросами - 0.4 секунды. Копайте в сторону базы данных. Ну и профайлер включите, гляньте время выполнения запросов.

Answer (score 1):

Если наугад, то классический совет - вместо `localhost` написать `127.0.0.1`, как средство против тормозящего DNS-a.

А так - только профилировать. Смотреть, на что конкретно уходит эта секунда.